# Unable to import modules from 'math' in Python

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I've hit this weird issue were I'm unable to import from the math module in Python. However importing the entire module works.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/analysis_routines/visar_analysis.py in <module>()
     16
     17 from core import scopes as cscopes
---> 18 from core import plot as cplot
     19 from core.plot import ImageData, IndexSelector
     20 from core.math import savitzky_golay

/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/core_diag/core/plot.py in <module>()
     10     sys.path.append(CORE_DIR)
     11
---> 12 from core import math as cmath
     13
     14 class ImageData(object):

/Users/bdhammel/Documents/research_programming/core_diag/core/math.py in <module>()
      3 import sys
      4 import math
----> 5 from math import factorial
      6 from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
      7

ImportError: cannot import name factorial
```

My directory structure is something like this

```
Main file
    from math import factorial # works fine here
    import custom_module

custom_module
    import math # works fine
    from math import factorial # breaks
```

I have no idea why this could be. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm working inside of a virtual environment.

Comment: Which Python version are you on? On Python 2, any attempts to import `math` inside `core.math` will import `core.math` instead of the built-in `math`.

Comment: gah... shoulda seen that one coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import the built-in `math` inside `core.math`, turn on absolute imports so you don't get `core.math` instead:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```